# Problem with timestamp formats in .find() in nodejs/express/Mongoose js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a collection like this;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d428c8b0edc602c155929c5"),
    "source" : "connection",
    "class" : "dns",
    "ts" : 1503528301.909886,
    "uid" : "C8avTr2cLyrJJxkN9",
}
```

If I print the key and type of key in mongo shell, I can see that ts actually is a string:
**ts string**

When I receive a query, I need to get the ts value from the URL and do a .find() query.
GET http://localhost:3300/alerts?**ts=1503528332.909886**&limit=100&page=1
startTs = req.query.ts

This may have to be converted to a ts without the '.' after the second. I have looked at converting 1503528332.909886 to float, multiply by 1000 1503528332909.886 and truncate to integer 1503528332909. I have also tried using both string and number format.

```
results.results = await model
    .find({"ts": {"$gte": <ts_variable: what format do I use?> }})
    .skip(startIndex)
    .exec();
res.paginatedResults = results;
```

If I only use ".find({})" and not try to select based on ts, everything works as expected. Appreciate any tips you have.

Comment: How about `Math.floor(ts * 1000)`

Comment: Can you still change the field type for 'ts' or is that not possible?

Comment: The object you are sharing shows ts as numeric, yet you also say it is a string? What fi define in your Mongoose schema?

Comment: I do not have control over the collection and can't change the type

Comment: The schema I use is according to what I found when listing key and key type. ts: { type: String, required: true },

Comment: @dohab: I tried Math.round(). This should be same result or?

Comment: Not the same value, but same result. I think. anyways, does that solve the problem?

Comment: @Samuel - it seems strange as you say. When I run these commands in mongo, it says string, but when I do a find it looks like a number not a string.
    > var schematodo = db.alerts.findOne()
    > for (var key in schematodo) { print (key, typeof key) ; }
    _id string
    source string
    class string
    sensor string
    ts string
    uid string